# Convert/Maintain Dates in Header from Excel to R

Tags: r, excel, date

I have an Excel spreadsheet with dates in the header. I want to import the spreadsheet into R, presumably using the read.xlsx() function. However, the dates are converted to a string of the internal value from Excel with an "X" in the front. I am hoping to keep the dates as a Date class, or convert the strings to a Date. I understand I could use as.Date() if the date was at least in a format, or the number of days from a specified origin, but it has the "X".

Thank you very much for the help.

Eg.

the excel spreadsheet "Practice"

```
Sample  09-Jul  10-Jul  11-Jul
1   3   10  2
2   5   0   
3   1   0   0
```

then in R:

```
practice<-read.xlsx("Practice.xlsx")

Sample X42925 X42926 X42927
1      1      3     10      2
2      2      5      0     NA
3      3      1      0      0

practice2=gather(practice,Date,value,-Sample,na.rm=TRUE)

Sample   Date value
1      1 X42925     3
2      2 X42925     5
3      3 X42925     1
4      1 X42926    10
5      2 X42926     0
6      3 X42926     0
7      1 X42927     2
9      3 X42927     0

practice2$Date=as.Date(practice2$Date)

Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value `X42925` is an Excel serial date, corresponding roughly to the date which is 42925 days after January 1, 1900.  We can convert these serial dates to R dates using `as.Date` with an appropriate origin.

You should be able to convert your Date column using something like the following.  This assumes the dates, prefixed by `X`, were read in as text.

```
dates <- as.numeric(substr(practice2$Dates, 2, nchar(practice2$Dates)))
practice2$Dates <- as.Date(dates, origin = '1899-12-30')
```

## Demo

Comment: This worked perfectly on my whole data set, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the Excel file as a .csv instead. That converts your data and dates into plain text, which should import into R with no problem.

Alternatively, try one of the methods here:
http://www.milanor.net/blog/read-excel-files-from-r/

Good luck!

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using read.csv because my whole data set is to be updated often and I wanted to write the code so that I can run it without having to save separate .csv every time it is, but thank you nonetheless!